# How to pass an integer value from 5 different textboxes to 2 different textboxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winforms application that has several buttons. It requires the user to click a button, however many times they need, that button1 click event then, adds an integer value inside textbox1, that integer value increments with each click of button1. And then I have button2 that when clicked, it subtracts from the integer value inside textbox1.

Now I also have textbox2, textbox3, textbox4, textbox5 and textbox6 doing the same thing each with their own pair of buttons to add and subtract. they all work independently from each other. Txtbox1,2,3,4,5,6 are the senders.

My problem comes when trying to have the integer value inside txtbox1, txtbox2, txtbox3, txtbox4, txtbox5 and txtbox6 pass onto txtbox7 and txtbox8, which are the receiving txtboxes. Each one of those txtboxes also have two buttons that add values and subtracts values. I'm able to get txtbox1 pass values onto txtbox7 & txtbox8 with no issue. The issue starts when I use the same code to have all the other txtboxes pass the int value to txtbox7 & txtbox8, the input from one of the 6 txtboxes will overwrite one another.

e.g. If I click 5 times on txtbox1 it passes the int 5 onto txtbox1, txtbox7 & txtbox8, but if then I go and click 2 times on txtbox2 then txtbox7 & 8 the value of 5 is not gone and it shows the new value of 2 instead. What I want to happen is, when any of those buttons gets clicked the value that passes onto the the 2 receiving txtboxes needs to be added to the int value that was already there. I don't know if that's explanatory enough. This is my code.

```
private void button1Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  AddToTexBox1(1);
}

private void AddToTextBox1(int changeBy)
{
  if (int.TryParse(txtBox1.Text, out int value))
  {
     value += changeBy;
     txtBox1.Text = value.ToString();
     txtBox7.Text = value.ToString();
     txtBox8.Text = value.ToString();
  }
  else
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Invalid Integer in TextBox!");
  }

}

private void Btn2Subtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     AddToTextBox1(-1);
}
```

That code is working fine for txtBox 1 and txtBox7 & txtBox8 but when I try to use the same for the other txtBoxes it doesn't work as expected. Any help would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with some code I had used at another Winforms project I had. I found the solution to my problem. This is what I did.

```
       TextBox[] txtbox;


        public FormOne()
        {
            InitializeComponent();



            Sqlconn con = new Sqlconn();

            txtbox = new TextBox[] { txtBox1, txtBox2, txtBox3, txtBox4, txtBox5, txtBox6, txtBox7};

            foreach (TextBox text in txtbox)
                text.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtbox_TextChanged);

           }

           private void txtbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int value = 0;
            int total = 0;
            foreach (TextBox text in txtbox)
            {
                if (int.TryParse(text.Text, out value))
                    total += value;
            }
            txtBox7.Text = total.ToString();
            txtBox8.Text = total.ToString();

            private void FormOne_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
```

Thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Your current problem is that you operate on the values stored in the textboxes directly. So when you do:

```
txtBox7.Text = value.ToString();
```

You don't chek the value currently stored in *txtBox7*.

So you can follow 2 paths to resolve it:

1. Use the same parsing to int to get value out of your *txtBox7* and put it in a variable, then add value to this variable and only then save it back into target TextBox.
2. You could have some model behind your logic (in case those numbers represent something) and update the model (by putting numbers into model's properties according to your "business" rules). After that you synchronize your UI (TextBoxes) with the model by putting the values from model to TextBoxes. Ideally you'd like to use data binding for it (in order for your UI to be refreshed automatically after your model changes).

Here is the code example for 1.:

```
if (int.TryParse(txtBox1.Text, out int value) &&
    int.TryParse(txtBox7.Text, out int oldValue7) &&
    int.TryParse(txtBox7.Text, out int oldValue8)
    )
{
    value += changeBy;
    oldValue7 += value;
    oldValue8 += value;
    txtBox1.Text = value.ToString();
    txtBox7.Text = oldValue7.ToString();
    txtBox8.Text = oldValue8.ToString();
}
```

In case you need more information regarding data binding please see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding). You'll have to spend time learning and getting used to this approach, but it'll allow you to decouple your model logic from the UI, which is beneficial for complicated models and UIs.

Here is the example of what I meant by introducing a separate class for your business rules:

```
class MyModel
{
  public int MyFirstInputValue {get; set;}
  public int MySecondInputValue {get; set;}

  public int MyFirstResultValue {get; private set;}
  public int MySecondResultValue {get; private set;}

  public void RunMyCalculationLogic()
  {
    // your calculations go here...
    MyFirstResultValue = MyFirstInputValue + MySecondInputValue;
    MySecondResultValue = MyFirstInputValue - MySecondInputValue;
  }
}
```

Then you use this model more or less like this:

```
var myModel = new MyModel();
myModel.MyFirstInputValue = 1; // parse value from input textBox1
myModel.MySecondInputValue = 2; // parse value from input textBox2
myModel.RunMyCalculationLogic();
// TODO: use results from MyFirstResultValue and MySecondResultValue to populate textBoxes you need
```

I hope that's enough for you to get started.

Comment: Stas Ivanov I tried your code but it causes txtbox7 & 8 to show numbers that are added by 5, 6 or 9 times more than what shows on txtbox1. In other words, I click on the button on txtbox1 twice and the value that should be passed to txtboxes 7 & 8 should be 2, instead it shows the value of 6.

Comment: @Yorelis, the logic you want to implement is not entirely clear to me. Could you please describe the rules briefly but precisely in your question? Another thing you could do is to play with my code and see if you are able to make it work. It currently gives you new behavior, right?

Comment: Stas Ivanov What I want is for the value entered in each one of those textboxes to be passed to 2 other textboxes in this case those boxes will be txtBox7 & txtBox8 they need to have the values from those other textboxes. So if I enter the value of 5 in txtbox1 then I enter the value of 4 in txtbox2 then I enter the value of 2 in txtbox3 and I the value of 1 in txtbox4 and the value of 2 in txtbox5 and the value of 3 in txtbox6 the result will be that both txtbox7 and txtbox8 should show a value of 17 but txtbox7 & 8

Comment: Do you want to calculate the sum of them? So what does this have to do with "add&subtract"?

Comment: Kyle Wang Yes I need the values being passed on to textbox7 & 8 from txtboxes 1,2,3,4,5,6 to be calculated. I need the 6 textboxes to pass their numeric values individually to textboxes 7 & 8 and to calculate those values but if the user needs to subtract from any of those values to be able to do so as well. with my code I've managed to get txtbox1 to do just that. But I can't get the other txtboxes 7 & 8 to keep calculating the values passed from all the other txtboxes, once I enter a value into any of the other txtboxes the values in txtbox 7 & 8 gets overwritten.

Comment: @Yorelis that's why IMO it's better to encapsulate this logic into separate class and only do synchronization with this class' fields in UI layer (aka poor man's bindings).

Comment: Stas Ivanov I tried your code and it will cause a different behavior than what I want. It causes the values entered into the sender txtboxes to be calculated3 and 4 times more and show incorrect numbers on the receiving txtboxes. I do not know how to make your code work, I am rather new to c#

Comment: @Yorelis I added one more example to my answer. Looks like I've done it too late, but it still might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your life would be a lot easier if you would use NumericUpDown controls instead of textboxes. You could set all your NUDs to default value 0, write one value changed event handler for them (link all the NUD's value changed events to the same one handler) that has a single line of code:

```
nud7.Value = nud1.Value + nud2.Value + nud3.Value ...
```

If you were to put nud1 to nud6 into a class wide array in the constructor then you could even use LINQ to simplify that to:

```
nud7.Value = myNuds.Sum(n => n.Value);
```

---

Here's a step by step- do this in a new project. It should take about 10 mins:

- make a new windows forms app
- drop 8 numeric up downs on the form
- select them all, set their minvalue and value to 0, set the max value to something relevant
- select the first 6 only
- go to the properties grid, click the lightning bolt, find the event that relates to value changed (probably called ValueChanged, I'm not at a pc to test right now) and write "AllChanged" in the box next to it, press return
- code view appears. Put that first code I posted (the one to add all the values and store the result in numeric updown 7's Value) in the event handler
- run the project

I'm not sure why you have two totals boxes.. but I'm sure you can sort that out

Be careful not to add the same event handler to box 7; you'll cause an infinite loop that will overflow the stack

Comment: Caius Jard I had it with numericupdown controls and then I changed it, now I just don't have enough time to change it back. I have to present this project on Monday. I just wanted to have that functionality so that it would be easier for the users to enter the data without forgetting to add those values. Thank you

Comment: Come on; it'll take about 5 minutes to swap the textboxes for nud. Nud already have clicky buttons to increment and decrement so it'll save a boatload of work. Give the nuds the same names as the tb they replace then fix all the compiler errors like "nunericupdown doesn't have a property x".. then rename the nuds if you want and all the code will update. Take a copy of your code before you start. If you can't get what I advised working in thirty mins, bin it

Comment: (Appreciating that time is of the essence here, i made an edit so you can step by step implement my recommendation as a quick Demo)